# browser based Image captioning tool that is open source?

Tags: javascript, rich-internet-application

looking for a browser based tool (sorta like WYSIWYG editor) but which allows the user to overlay text on a photo. It should be supported croww browser and I been searching github but coming up short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

https://github.com/adityab/memecached

it's written in Javascript, which is obviously good (because you can put it in the browser easily, that's what it's intended for), and uses mongodb (which I think would probably scale well in your case, since you wouldn't need complex operations on the database really). Downside is that it relies on Dropbox, so you might have to change that unless you like that feature.

Comment: is there a demo of this? looks good...

Comment: @KimJongWoo There isn't a demo, but if you look at the very bottom of the git page under **How to Run** it has instructions that look pretty easy, for linux at least :)